# How to truncate a string in codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter

here is my controller which will get the url information from some model function and passed it to my view.

```
class MyController extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //load the settings model
        //some model

        //load the text helper
        $this->load->helper('text');
    }

    public function index()
    {

        //call the model function to get the Url data
        $data['urllist'] = //call the model function and get the array and store it to urllist; 

        //load the view
        $this->load->view("myview",$data);

    }
}
```

and my view is

```
    <body>
        <?php

            /*
                //$longurl is an array element and its value is 
                some thing like 
                http://example.com/sdsds/sdsdsd/sdsdsdsd/sdsdsd/sdsdsd

                 i want to truncate it about 20 characters
            */
            $lurl=character_limiter($longurl, 20);
            echo $lurl; 

        ?>
    </body>
```

but it shows full url. can I use **character_limiter** in view? or I have to truncate it in my controller and passed it to view?

Comment: Do all logic in a controller.

Comment: what do mean about truncate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you had to use ellipsize() function from text helpers

> This function will strip tags from a string, split it at a defined maximum length, and insert an ellipsis.
>
> The first parameter is the string to ellipsize, the second is the
>   number of characters in the final string. The third parameter is where
>   in the string the ellipsis should appear from 0 - 1, left to right.
>   For example. a value of 1 will place the ellipsis at the right of the
>   string, .5 in the middle, and 0 at the left.
>
> An optional forth parameter is the kind of ellipsis. By default,
>   … will be inserted.

```
$str = 'this_string_is_entirely_too_long_and_might_break_my_design.jpg';

echo ellipsize($str, 32, .5);
```

Produces:

```
this_string_is_e…ak_my_design.jpg
```

[ellislab.com official documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/text_helper.html)